# I can not open the OMNeT++ IDE

Tags: java, c++, omnet++, inet

I can not start the OMNeT++ ide. Everytime I get the error "An error has occurred. See the log file".
So I open the log file and it does not help me.

(see below)

Yesterday I could work on it with no Problems. I didnt do anything or changed anything I just simulated as the last days with simuLTE from GitHub. And then this.

`````
!MESSAGE Cannot add lte to the list of segments in 
lte::simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
!STACK 0 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$CyclicPathException: Cannot add lte to the list of segments in 
lte::simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$TreePathCompiler.addParent(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:537)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:600)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getParents(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:328)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getParentElement(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1680)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getParentElement(TreeViewer.java:557)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1619)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedElements(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2382)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.frameChanged(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:72)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.CommonNavigatorFrameSource.frameChanged(CommonNavigatorFrameSource.java:52)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.handlePropertyChange(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:171)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource$1.propertyChange(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:48)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.firePropertyChange(FrameList.java:90)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.setCurrent(FrameList.java:205)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.gotoFrame(FrameList.java:162)
    at 
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.GoIntoAction.run(GoIntoAction.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at 
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 0 2019-08-26 19:38:50.288
!MESSAGE Cannot add P/lte to the list of segments in simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$CyclicPathException: Cannot add P/lte to the list of segments in simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$TreePathCompiler.addParent(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getParents(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getParentElement(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1680)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 4 0 2019-08-26 19:38:50.272
!MESSAGE Cannot add lte to the list of segments in lte::simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$CyclicPathException: Cannot add lte to the list of segments in lte::simulations::lte::P/lte::plugins:: as a parent.
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$TreePathCompiler.addParent(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getParents(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getParentElement(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1680)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getParentElement(TreeViewer.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1619)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedElements(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.frameChanged(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.CommonNavigatorFrameSource.frameChanged(CommonNavigatorFrameSource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.handlePropertyChange(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource$1.propertyChange(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.firePropertyChange(FrameList.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.setCurrent(FrameList.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.FrameList.gotoFrame(FrameList.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.framelist.GoIntoAction.run(GoIntoAction.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)````

Any ideas? Thanks!
`````

Answer (score 1):

**[SUGGESTION, NOT ANSWER]** I don't know what could be exactly causing this in your machine. but I might suggest to check [this](https://omnetpp.org/articles/2019/07/04/omnetpp-docker.html) using official docker builds might eliminate dependency issues.

Comment: Fixed it. 
I tried to run other ned files and then I got an DLL-Error (needed to update Windows and install it again :)))  ) now it works. Wow... this truly left me speechless….

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it :) ... sorry for Windows :D but maybe you can add an answer describing the fix or change you comment into answer and accept it.